# Changing Android minSDKVersion from 9 to 10 breaks program

Tags: android, xml, parsing, sdk, sax

Getting a weird problem trying to set up my AndroidManifest.

I have been developing my app with the 2.3.3 SDK (API Level 10) but I realized that my minSDKVersion was set to 9 in the manifest the whole time.  However, when I change the API level to 10 to get ready for release, my program seems to lose the ability to fetch data from websites (I'm using a SAX XML Parser) and the ability to write cache files.

I have checked the google API differences spec, and I don't think I'm using anything that is deprecated.

Any ideas?

===LOGCAT OUTPUT===
http://pastebin.com/T3DgAuSA

I made sure to give it internet permissions as well:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack trace suggests that you are trying to make Http request in UI thread(eg. `UrlConectioin` in `onCreate()` method). Android doesn't allow synchronous HTTP request. You should put all your http requests in `AsyncTask`. It looks like this restriction was introduced in Api 10. Look at this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7823534/265597).